# How to use Amazon Alexa as output speaker using WiFi?

Tags: api, wifi, amazon, alexa

Amazon Alexa is used as speaker using Bluetooth, but I want to Alexa as speaker using WiFi and/or with an HTTP request. I want to send voice from my application to my physical Alexa device and use the Alexa as a speaker.

Is there any API endpoint or library?